# Spring boot mail

Tags: spring-boot, email

Hi Hope some one can help me..I need to run test case for sending mail and body of the mail should be taken from message.properties

for eg:

SimpleMailMessage message1 = new SimpleMailMessage();

```
    message1.setFrom("develop@gmail.com");
    message1.setTo(doctor.getEmail());
    message1.setSubject("event.appointment.slot.user.repeat");
    message1.setText("You have one "+eventData.getTitle()+"an appointment at"+eventData.getStart()+"to"+eventData.getEnd()+"was cancelled by patient.");
    emailSender.send(message1);
```

In message.properties

event.appointment.cancelled=Appointment Canceled.

I receive mail but it is same as event.appointment.slot.user.repeat in subject as i am new to this it will be helpful if someone can guide me through this

thanks in advance

i tried with $[0].code but it is showing me error on [0] which is not accepting

Comment: not sure if You want to use property in subject or in email body, if You want subect try using `@Value("${event.appointment.slot.user.repeat}") private String subject;`

Comment: can you please elaborate as my other test case is passing with same scenario but not this test case

Comment: in Your example `message.properties` has `event.appointment.cancelled=Appointment Canceled.` but You set subject as `"event.appointment.slot.user.repeat"` I am not sure what you wan to do